# document.getElementsByName(...)[0] is undefined when javascript value is insert to the .net textbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, .net

I want to insert value from JavaScript variable to the textbox value. In JavaScript variable data is coming very well but when that variable data I am storing in the .net textbox using JavaScript at that time this type of error is coming.

Here is my code

```
<form>

<asp:TextBox name="password" ID="txt_pass" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>

<asp:Button ID="btn_captcha" runat="server" Text="Gen. Pass." OnClientClick="return false;" ClientIDMode="Static"/>

<script>
    $(function () {
        $(document).on("click", "#btn_captcha", function (e) {
            var length = 5,
        charset = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789",
        retVal = "";
            for (var i = 0, n = charset.length; i < length; ++i) {
                retVal += charset.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * n));
            }
            alert(retVal);
            document.getElementsByName('password')[0].value = retVal;
        });
    });
    </script>

</form>
```

Comment: Flag this question as a .net question as it is not just a javascript question

Comment: @Zuks you could add those tags as well. Even though mods will have to accept those edits

Comment: @Sagar add them how seeing that I can't edit the post?

Comment: check the page source as it appears **in the browser** - name attribute on ASP controls means nothing for the final HTML the browser gets

Comment: @Zuks Weird. I was able to do it. You have a rep greater than mine. Is there a limit to number of edits you can do?

Comment: @Sagar I have no idea. The "edit" button is grayed out and I can't press it. And also I have not done any edit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Id instead of name

```
document.getElementById('<%= txt_pass.ClientID %>').value = retVal;
```

or

```
document.querySelector('[id$=_txt_pass]').value = retVal;
```

Comment: except ASP (usually) mangles ID's - unless that textbox was also `ClientIDMode="Static"`

Comment: Modified the above code, since it runat is server, we can use this @JaromandaX

Comment: yes, that's the other way of doing it - a third (probably not very safe though) way would be `document.querySelector('[id$=_txt_pass]').value = retVal;`

Comment: We can use queryselector too.. that too works well, Edited the code above as you said.

Answer (score 0):

I think that your problem is that the textbox name and id you are looking for is not static thats why javascript cannot find the element. Press F12 use developer tools to verify the above input's name and id and then use a static one.